# Laravel :Foreign key constraint in incorrectly formed

Tags: laravel

I think everything i wrote correctly.When i run "php artisan migrate" command PDOException appear.I went through all over relevant post in stackoverflow.But i am not getting any solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V068A.png)

[PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_jobs`.`#sql-
  ec4_170` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: What is the storage engine? `myISAM` or `INNODB`? Because `myISAM` doesn't support foreign key restraints.

Answer (score 2):

The error: `Can't create table laravel_jobs`

So I don't think the problem is with the `Resume` table migration.

Answer (score 1):

you should create your foreign keys after creating the table. like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

        Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->string('class_code');
            $table->string('username')->nullable();
            $table->string('email_address')->nullable();
            $table->uuid('contact_id')->nullable();
            $table->uuid('customer_id')->nullable();
            $table->char('password_hash', 64)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('active')->nullable();
            $table->string('remember_token', 100)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('user', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contact')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customer')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

you may however need to ensure the order that your migrations are ran is correct. Therefore you may want your create table function to create nullable foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update your migration code like :

```
Schema::create('resume', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamp();
});
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the following terms:

```
1. The datatype of id column on users table and user_id on resume table are same.
2. If id is unsigned integer or big integer then user_id will be unsigned 
   integer or big integer.
3. Length of id on users table and user_id on resume table will be same.
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer for your question the user @lalitesh already found the solution

[laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-uuid-my-foreign-key-constraints-fail)

i hope you find your solution